# Как перебрать циклом данные из бд?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица Games:
[image: таблица]

Какой код для перебора данных нужно написать чтобы результат соответствовал данному результату:

Игра 1
Партия 1
User 1: 43
User 2: 11
User 3: 87

Партия 2
User 1: 34
User 2: 43
User 3: 65

Игра 2
Партия 1
User 1: 90
User 2: 21
User 3: 66

Answer (score 1):

Сначала отсортируйте данные по возрастанию Игры, Партии, Юзера

```sql
SELECT * FROM Games ORDER BY game_id, party_id, user_id
```

А потом выводите в PHP, начиная новую таблицу (или что вы используете), когда данные из соответствующего столбца изменяются